# Git/Github - Proper way to checkout current remote branch

Tags: git, github

We are using a simple Github flow where the remote Github repository has Master (for production) and Develop (for development).

I want to checkout branches from Develop (remote) and merge my changes back into Develop (remote).

What's the proper way to checkout a new branch from Develop (remote) so that I know I have the current remote status of the branch?

- for reference I'm trying to use this flow http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ . Perhaps I should just modify `$ git checkout -b myfeature develop` to checkout from origin/develop?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you update the remote tracking branch with

```
git fetch origin
```

Then you update your local develop branch with

```
git checkout develop
git merge origin/develop
```

or

```
git push . origin/develop:develop # you avoid having to checkout the branch to update it
```

Then make your feature off of the latest develop with:

```
git checkout -b myfeature develop
```

Double check with git log:

```
git log -1 --decorate
```

You should see the commit and the fact that develop, orgin/develop, myfeature and HEAD all point to the same thing. You can now work in the new branch and the work will be the latest as of the point in time when you fetched.

Comment: cool thanks. that's pretty much what I thought. couple of cool things to check out there tho. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `git checkout -tb myfeature origin/develop` (assuming you've named the remote `origin`), and Git will track the remote branch for you.

Comment: `git checkout -t origin/develop` should do the same thing if you don't have develop yet.